# Stackoverflow Exception with LinqToSQL compiled queries

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stack-overflow, compiled-query

We're experiencing a strange situation where a LinqToSQL that has compiled queries within it causes a stackoverflow exception when ran locally but when in a live environment runs fine without any issues.

The query contains a number of joins and on the `select` calls 2 different compiled queries to calculate a couple of values. If we comment these queries out then the query runs fine. It doesn't seem to be a specific compiled query either as just running a single one causes the issue.

The point at which the debugger breaks for the exception is no help either as it's a line of code that had nothing to do with the query being executed.

Comment: Whats the exception?

Comment: It's a stackoverflow exception

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today. I switched to Visual Studio 2015 from 2103 and compiled a library without recompiling its dependencies. In my case, it looked like a compiler problem.

A clean and a rebuild (dependencies included) solved the problem.